# Customizar Paginator en DataTable de PrimeVue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

Estoy teniendo un problema grave para solucionar un asunto sobre PrimeVue, (no puedo compartir el código debido a que va en contra de las políticas de mi trabajo, pero si puedo redactarles mi situación)

Al utilizar un DataTable de PrimeVue:

[image: Datatable de primevue]

Necesito saber, como puedo cambiar los estilos correctamente, ya he logrado avanzar y obtener algunos resultados, pero, continuo a tener mucha dificultad en lograr que resulte tal cual el wireframe aprobado por el cliente, necesito saber como poner algo escrito al lado izquierdo del dropdown, dicho dropdown debe estar al lado izquierdo, y el contador de paginas (para pasar de una a otra) debe estar en su totalidad al lado derecho, anexo una foto de como se tendría que ver:

[image: Como deberia quedar]

Necesito lograr algo como eso, pero no encuentro solucion por ninguna lado, no se si alguna ya se ha topado con esto

Cabe resaltar que DataTable en si utiliza el componente de "Paginator" de Primevue, por tanto, deberia permitirme ser mas flexible con los estilos, sin embargo, no consigo hacerlo, pido su ayuda!

Comment: Te recomiendo que crees un [repro] de todos modos: abstraé lo más posible los datos como para que no sea el código tal cual como se utiliza en la empresa.